# Update <p> when selection is submitted jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to change p#switch-on-id when a user selects an option THEN clicks submit.

The jquery switches the p#switch-on-id when the user clicks an option but if he selects another option it switches without pressing submit.  I only need it to switch when the user clicks submit.

Thanks for the help!

```
<p id="switch-on-submit">hello</p>

    <select multiple="no">
        <option selected="selected">one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
        <option>four</option>
   </select>
   <button id="submit">
    add
   </button>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){

       $("select").change(function(){
           $("select option:selected").each(function(){
           str = $(this).text();
       });
       $("p#switch-on-submit").text(str);
       }).change();

       });

});
```

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matty91/uvgh67q3/1/)

Comment: You have a `.change()` inside your `.on()`.  So anytime you `change` the select option, it will fire away.  Remove the `.change()` inside your `.on()`.  I believe you're just trying to get the value of the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: https://jsfiddle.net/0x7kg43n/

Hope I understood you correctly. You only need a onClick event for the button. Inside this event you get the selected text from the select box and add the text to your p-element.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
$("p#switch-on-submit").text($("select option:selected").text());

});
```

Comment: Yup!!! That's it! haha thanks! I knew it was something simple.  I will accept the answer. thanks again

Comment: @matty I am glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just trying to get the value of the select on submit.  But you're using `.change()`.  `.change()` listens for when a select box is changed.  So it literally means `when select changes, do this function`.

You'll have to get the value of the selected option:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){
    var str = $('select option:selected').text();
    //Do something with thisText here:
    $("p#switch-on-submit").text(str);
});
```